# PySide2 no distribution found on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5, pyside2

I am trying to install PySide2 through pip but it throws me this error:

> Downloading/unpacking PySide2
>
> Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PySide2
>   Cleaning up...
>
> No distributions at all found for PySide2

I run pip also with `-v` option and I noticed that it check if there is any PySide2 wheel available for my platform but it doesn't find one.
I visited this [url](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/QtForPython/pyside2/) where there are all the available wheel for PySide2. It seems to me that there is at least one good for my platform, why pip keep saying the opposite?

Here some useful output:

```
hostnamectl
Chassis: vm
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-121-generic
Architecture: x86_64

cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
```

I am using a virtual environment with this Python version:

```
python --version
Python3.5.2
```

Why, for example, this wheel is not compatible?
PySide2-5.11.0-5.11.0-cp35.cp36-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded pip and now I am able to install PySide2

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```